# hypothetically speaking vs theoretically speaking

Tags: synonyms

"They say the sky is blue"......hypothetically speaking or theoretically speaking (which is the right phrase to use if you thinking of evoking a debate on the matter).

If am thinking its any colour but blue.

Comment: "Theoretically" carries a *slight* intimation that there is, in fact, some "real" theory behind your statement.  "Hypothetically", on the other hand, permits you to speak in terms of fairies and magical potions, if you wish.

Comment: I'd choose a different example, as terms need defining here. Is 'is blue' being used in the sense 'appears blue to an observer', and what truly constititutes 'having the property of blueness'?

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks - it's also supported by how the hypothesis and theory are used in scientific terms. (theory is a tested and verified hypothesis)

Answer (score 1):

I would say theoretically as your sentence seems to deal with the [Electromagnetic Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetism)
. Unless you are speaking to a specific hypothesis that was mentioned earlier in the conversation. The answer your looking for, I'm afraid, is highly contextual.